# OpenCV image pointer not working as expected

Tags: image, pointers, opencv

So I have to do some operations on part of an image. The operation is not relevant (i dont change this code at all), but the way i create the pointer changes the results i get. I dont understand why that happens.

Why does this code gets the result I want:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 70; ++row) {
    for(int col = 48; col < 208; ++col) {
        uchar* p = c.ptr(row+col);
        *p = (1-circuloBinario.at<unsigned char>(row,col-48))*(*p) + circuloBinario.at<unsigned char>(row,col-48)*limite;
    }
}
```

And this one doesnt?

```
for(int row = 0; row < 70; ++row) {
    uchar* p = c.ptr(row+48);
    for(int col = 48; col < 208; ++col) {
        *p = (1-circuloBinario.at<unsigned char>(row,col-48))*(*p) + circuloBinario.at<unsigned char>(row,col-48)*limite;
         p++;
    }
}
```

By the way, I dont get any errors with the second code, the problem is that the result I get is not what I expect (it starts modifying the image from a row bigger than 0 and starts from column 0 instead of 48).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mat::ptr` returns a pointer to the specified matrix **row**.

See the documentation here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr

So neither `c.ptr(row+col)` nor `c.ptr(row+48)` make sense because you should only be passing a row index to the `ptr` function.

Comment: I see. Yeah it was quite confusing why the first one worked while the second one didnt, but it makes more sense if neither of them should work. I will change my code then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use Mat::pt is apparently incorrect, as mentioned by M456.

If you want to modify the value of some elements of the matrix, why don't you use the following syntax?

```
c.at<element_type>(row, col) = new_value;
```

Comment: I think I will use it like that now, I was just trying the other way and those weird results got me confused. Thank you :)